# Load Content automatically in Django app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-1.10

I'm working on a Django (1.10 & Python3) project in which I need to implement a logic as:
We have articles from various categories, the user needs to tag these articles, mean when user read articles then he needs to provide his feedback rather it's relevant or irrelevant to his situation.

We have to provide user's a list of categories when user select a category then all of the articles from that particular category will be available one by one to the user, mean it will show the first article to the user, when he tagged this article it will load next article automatically and also keep the user's tagging info because it's not necessary to tag all articles at once, user can tag few at a time when he can start from where has was stopped again.

**In simple:**

Would it be possible to send the user straight from their choice of a Category to the "Article Tagging" page with the next article to be tagged automatically loaded up and ready to be tagged, and the system keeps track of what the next article is that needs to be tagged?

How can I accomplish this bit of functionality in python & Django?

I'm new to python & Django, help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is too broad.

Comment: Hi, @AstikAnand ! how can I improve this question? please!

Comment: Now, it seems quite good.

Answer (score 1):

You can process the selection as a request and then in **views** filter all articles on the basisof that selection.

Then paginate all those collected contents by `next` and `previous` available as django [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/) features.

Comment: Hi, @AstikAnand ! how can we load next article automatically?

Comment: You need to write views, collect data regarding that particular tag. And then use pagination from the link.

Comment: Pagination isn't my problem, I need to automate the page loading when the user submits first page the next one load automatically, and also it should start from where the user leaves it last time when he logged in back!   How can I achieve that! thank you!

Comment: You need to break your thoughts first, try doing things one by one. Why you want to achieve all things at once.

Comment: Actually, I have done with pagination, now automate the loading is my next task!

Comment: Are you able to show the articles pagination after he tags it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156189/discussion-between-abdul-rehman-and-astik-anand).